How to get `mypy` to raise errors/warnings about using the `typing` package instead of built in types
Currently I have a bunch of code that does this:
from typing import Dict
foo: Dict[str, str] = []

In Python 3.9+, it is preferable to use the built-in types (source):
foo: dict[str, str] = []

Is there a way to configure mypy to raise an error/warning when my code uses Dict instead of dict?

Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71766915/raising-deprecationwarning-in-mypy-for-pep-585

Mypy issue with some context around PEP 585: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/7907

Implemented in pyupgrade, ruff's UP006, flake8 plugin, and probably somewhere else. Using a deprecated alias is not a typing problem - it's a linting problem perfectly solved by linters. Why do you want mypy to provide these diagnostics?

According to the mypy maintainers, this fuctionality will not be implemented because it has already been implemented by formatters like ruff:

This is already implemented by linters such as Ruff (https://docs.astral.sh/ruff/rules/non-pep585-annotation/). That doesn't mean mypy can't also implement support for checks like this, but it does mean the return on investment for mypy to add this feature is lower.

Source
